# ui-sref not working with child state from ionic modal

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ui-sref

I create modal in which I create a button that open child state named `menu.friend`

that I defined it like that:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
.state('menu', {
  url: '/menu',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'views/menu.html'
 })
 .state('menu.friend', {
 url: '/map',
     views: {
    'menuContent': {
     templateUrl: 'views/map.html'   
     }
     }   
  })
```

In my ion-modal-view, I put this button code:

```
<button  ui-sref="menu.friend">
 Add event
</button>
```

But nothing is displayed. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i Think your code is working fine. Thing is modal has a z-index whicch is more than a view so it is sitting on top of the new view.

so do something like this

```
<button  ui-sref="menu.friend" ng-click="modalClose()">
 Add event
</button>
```

Also I prefer more cleaner state  urls , something like this

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

```
$stateProvider
.state('menu', {
  url: '/menu',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'views/menu.html'
 })
 .state('menu.friend', {
 url: '/menu/friend',
     views: {
    'menuContent': {
     templateUrl: 'views/map.html'   
     }
     }   
  })
```